# volatile uint32_t on cortex-m3

Tags: c, cortex-m

This is my code:

```
volatile uint32_t value = *((volatile uint32_t *) 0xA0000000); // here `value` is 12498
value *= 2; // here `value` is still 12498
value |= 0x0000001; // still 12498
```

When analysing the variable `value` in my debugger, it holds the same value on all lines. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps your debugger doesn't deal with volatiles correctly?

Comment: Why don't just use some tracing and check the behavior of the actual program by not relying on the debugger for the sake of verification.

Comment: What processor are you using?

Comment: By the way, are you reading a uint from the hard coded address `0xA0000000`? Now what neat trick is that for (or am I missing something)?

Comment: @DipSwitch: An ARM Cortex M3.

Comment: @Christian: It's a know place in the memory of my chip.

Comment: @Randomblue Ah Ok, hadn't thought about some non-desktop hardware.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembly code?  What toolset are you using?  (IAR, Keil, Rowley, other GNU-based, etc.)  Also what is the context of this?  For example, if exactly these 3 lines constituted the entire body of a function, an optimizer would realize that you aren't doing anything with value after the multiply & bitwise OR.  Bottom line: we need more information & context to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe your debugger isn't actually that good. When one of my tools doesn't seem to behave, I always check it against another tool.

Try to debug the old-fashioned way, with:

```
volatile uint32_t value = *((volatile uint32_t *) 0xA0000000);
printf ("A:%d\n", value);

value *= 2;
printf ("B:%d\n", value);

value |= 0x0000001;
printf ("C:%d\n", value);
```

or some other output method if `printf` is unavailable (it looks like you may be working in the embedded space).

See what you get with that - I'd be more inclined to trust `printf`-debugging than debuggers.

---

If your problem is not with `value` but instead with the memory at location `0xA0000000`, then it's working as expected.

You're manipulating the local variable, not the memory location. You need to write the value back, with something like:

```
*((volatile uint32_t *) 0xA0000000) = value;
```

---

However, given your use of volatile, it's entirely possible you just wanted a variable *pointer* to that location so that changes would reflect immediately.

If that's the case, you would need something along the lines of:

```
volatile uint32_t *pValue = (volatile uint32_t *) 0xA0000000;
*pValue *= 2;
*pValue |= 0x00000001;
```

In that case, the memory location would be changed at each instruction *without* having to explicitly write the value.

Comment: I do not have a `printf` at the moment because I'm developing for an embedded system.

Comment: Then you should find another way such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165654/cost-of-fprintf/5165813#5165813 and end up doing something with the character buffer (`puts` or output to serial port, etc).

Comment: http://github.com/dwelch67, look for hexstring, I use it everywhere, or make your own, octal is even easier, but most of us still working think in hex not octal.  doesnt require divides, shift mask and add/or for octal, a conditional required for hex, shove it out the uart or if you have a scope or logic analyzer shove it out parallel or other serial interface (at much faster than uart speed).

Answer (score 1):

1. It may be that your optimizer has noticed that `value` is an automatic variable whose address is never taken, and so has in effect ignored the fact that its volatile, since it happens to know something about the architecture it runs on, and has concluded that a conforming program cannot observe what sequence of reads and writes to it occurs even though the standard says this is observable. Obviously that's not very debugger-friendly, but I wouldn't be that surprised if it happens anyway. In effect the compiler would be assuming that you can't "see" the stack, which is false if you use a debugger, examine a core dump, mark the stack read-only and handle the resulting signals, etc. Check the disassembly, see whether the multipy/shift and the bit-set actually appear.
2. It may be that your debugger isn't tracking the value correctly, either because of (1) or otherwise.

Comment: 0xA0000000 is a something significant in the memory map of the board I'm working on.

Comment: It's not actually undefined otherwise embedded systems could never claim compliance with memory-mapped I/O. The standard states it's undefined only if "an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer" - invalid values include null, wrong alignment and an object after its lifetime but that's all it has to say. Whether 0xa0000000 is invalid is a matter for the implementation.

Comment: @pax: sure, it's actually one of those cases like `SHRT_MAX + 1`, where it's implementation-defined whether behavior is defined or not. So on a particular C implementation, not yet named here, that happens to be the one Randomblue is using, it's defined :-)

Answer (score 0):

try writing value to another temp variable and examine that value.  Sometimes this tricks the compiler/debugger into doing what you want.  AFAIK, volatile tells the compiler to always read the value, not necessarily to keep it around for writing if its never read.